# How to change the notification icon?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, notifications

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging service to send notifications, I want to change the notification icon and background if that is possible.
NOTE: I remark that when I send a message using FCM only the online devices receive the notification is there any way to send to all Devices ( the online devices and the other devices when they become Online)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, make a drawable around 40px or just use SVG if you can, and pass the icon below and make sure the icon is black or white only.

```
 val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("FCM")
            .setContentText("FCM notification")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

read more [here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar). And yes you only receive FCM notifications whenever you are online, once sent from the dashboard or backend it has some time before it expires.

Comment: what's  CHANNEL_ID and  pendingIntent ? and why must  i use only white or black icon ? and thank you for all.

Comment: Then you have to read  https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 0):

Does the manifest file contain the following piece of code?

```
        <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/main_icon" />

    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: i have one more QS help me please : I remark that when i send a message using FCM only the online devices receive the notification is there any way to send to all Devices ( the online devices and the other devices when they become Online ) ??